# How to sort legends alphabetically in plotly dash with category_orders function

Tags: python, sorting, plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-plot

I am using Plotly dash for creating a scatter plot. The legends I am getting in the final figure are randomly placed. I want to sort labels alphabetically from A to Z with `category_orders` function

```
fig = px.box(
            df,
            x=selected_x,
            y=selected_y,
            points='all',
            hover_data=hover_data,
            color=colour_by,
            width=800,
            height=600,
            labels={
                selected_y: "{} {}".format(selected_y_gene, selected_y),
                selected_x: "{} {}".format(selected_x_gene, selected_x),
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many labels, a simple alternative would be to use `categoryorder` e.g for x-axis using [Layout.xaxis](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-categoryorder).

Example using the iris dataset:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.box(
    df,
    x="species",
    y="sepal_length",
    points="all",
    width=800,
    height=600,
)
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder="category ascending")
```

[image: result]

If you wish to use `category_orders` in plotly.express.box:

```py
fig = px.box(
    df,
    x="species",
    y="sepal_length",
    points="all",
    category_orders=dict(species=['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']),
    width=800,
    height=600,
)
fig
```